# Putting a border for moving square

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener, keylistener

So basically im just playing around with movement systems for different purposes and having trouble making square stop right at the edge. Square moves off the side of screen by around 50% of the square it self and i cannot figure out why it is like that.

```
package SnakeMovement;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SnakeMovement extends Canvas implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    Timer timer = new Timer(5, this);

    int width, height;

    int xSize = 50, ySize = 50;
    int yPos = 0, xPos = 0, yVel = 0, xVel = 0;

    public SnakeMovement(int w, int h) {
        timer.start();

        width = w;
        height = h;

        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        setFocusable(true);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        g.fillRect(xPos, yPos, xSize, ySize);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        xPos += xVel;
        yPos += yVel;

        if (xPos >= width - xSize) {
            xPos = width - xSize;
            xVel = 0;
        }

        repaint();
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            yVel = -10;
            xVel = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            yVel = 10;
            xVel = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            xVel = -10;
            yVel = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            xVel = 10;
            yVel = 0;
        }

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }


}
```

I just want so square stops at each side of screen perfectly on the edge.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: You shouldn’t mix `Canvas` with a `Swing` UI. For a custom component, extend `JComponent`. Then, override `paintComponent` instead of `paint`.

Comment: @Holger so instead of me using a canvas i should make in my main class which is the 1 which has the jframe have jpanel to and then use JComponent in the lets saying movement class am i getting your advice corrently?

Comment: I don’t know your main class and didn’t say anything about it. It’s your class `SnakeMovement` which extends `Canvas` and I recommend extending `JComponent` instead. Be sure to have read [this part of the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)…

Comment: My main class just has the window initializer nothing much. All the code is in the SnakeMovement class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
private static final int BORDER_SIZE = 1;
private static final Color RECT_COLOR = Color.BLUE, BORDER_COLOR = Color.RED;

 @Override
 public void paint(Graphics g) {
     super.paint(g);
     g.setColor(BORDER_COLOR);
     g.fillRect(xPos, yPos, xSize, ySize);
     g.setColor(RECT_COLOR);
     g.fillRect(xPos+BORDER_SIZE, yPos+BORDER_SIZE, xSize-2*BORDER_SIZE, ySize-2*BORDER_SIZE);
}
```

The idea is to paint a full size rectangular using the border color. 
Then painting a smaller one (smaller by 2*BORDER_SIZE) using the rectangular color.

---

The following is [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve) of the above:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SnakeMovement extends Canvas implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    private static final int BORDER_SIZE = 1, DELAY = 100;
    private static final Color RECT_COLOR = Color.BLUE, BORDER_COLOR = Color.RED;
    private final int xSize = 50, ySize = 50;
    private int yPos = 0, xPos = 0, yVel = 5, xVel = 5;
    private final Timer timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);

    public SnakeMovement(int width, int height) {
        timer.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        setFocusable(true);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(BORDER_COLOR);
        g.fillRect(xPos, yPos, xSize, ySize);
        g.setColor(RECT_COLOR);
        g.fillRect(xPos+BORDER_SIZE, yPos+BORDER_SIZE, xSize-2*BORDER_SIZE, ySize-2*BORDER_SIZE);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        xPos += xVel;
        yPos += yVel;
        checkLimits();
        repaint();
    }

    //when canvas edge is reached emerge from the opposite edge
    void checkLimits(){
        //check x and y limits
        if (xPos >= getWidth()) {
            xPos = -xSize;
        }
        if (xPos < -xSize ) {
            xPos = getWidth();
        }

        if (yPos >= getHeight() ) {
            yPos = -ySize;
        }
        if (yPos < -ySize ) {
            yPos = getHeight();
        }
    }

    //two other behaviors when hitting a limit. uncomment the desired behavior  
    /*

        //when canvas edge is reached change direction
        void checkLimits(){
            //check x and y limits
            if (  xPos >= getWidth() - xSize ||  xPos <= 0) {
                xVel = - xVel;
            }

            if (  yPos >= getHeight() - ySize ||  yPos <= 0) {
                yVel = - yVel;
            }
        }
     */

    /*

        //when canvas edge is reached stop movement
        void checkLimits(){
            //check x and y limits
            if (  xPos >= getWidth() - xSize ||  xPos <= 0 ||  yPos >= getHeight() - ySize ||  yPos <= 0) {
                timer.stop();
            }
        }

     */

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            yVel = -10;
            xVel = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            yVel = 10;
            xVel = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            xVel = -10;
            yVel = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            xVel = 10;
            yVel = 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args0) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new SnakeMovement(500, 500));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Are you able to give a bit more explanation on how this would work as i dont really get how i can use the border to not let square go off the edge as it still happens.

Comment: See the additional info I added. "_not let square go off the edge as it still happens_" sorry I do not understand the problem

Comment: Added [mre] so you can run and test it.

Comment: OK so basically this is problem i get https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hLnA0f7kBFsax_SHbl59AR2U2HlFi7G8 using this code. 
```
if (xPos >= width + xSize) {
            xPos = width - xSize;
            xVel = 0;
        }
```
The square doesnt fully go of the edge just doesnt align properly and im confused.
If this helps you understand what is going on with my problem.

Comment: I believe the image in the link was not taken from the posted mre.  Other questions should be posted in a new post.

Comment: Ye it wasn't taken from the mre i understand how you use the x and y limits and it works kinda different to what i want + i understand that i need to ask on a new post but if you dont mind to try making it so the square cant move past the width and height like as soon as it gets to border it stops and cant go past it no more. Would be much appreciated if you can maybe give me some sort of solution or and idea how i can get that to work.

Comment: "_as it gets to border it stops_"  ? do you want the movement to stop completely when it hits one of the 4 canvas boundaries ?

Comment: Yes that is what im trying to achieve

Comment: Se my edited code: I introduced 3 versions of `checkLimits()` method.

Comment: OMG thanks that is perfect i can use this as a template to add more functions i just could not get it to work my way Thanks a lot. :D

Comment: You are most welcome. When you have new questions (posts) leave me a message here and I'll try to help

Comment: quick question maybe you will know this as its been a problem for me to get this right basically as this picture shows https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yUZ7D3h2e_DuxGuav1btstXsvZbqLemx the square doesnt align properly with the border on the left and the bottom no matter how much i try to change. Im using your second checkLimits code ive made a similar 1 and i had a problem before but can never find a solution.

Comment: Please post a question with an [mre] version of you code. Als add the desired behavior.